# MVVM visual studio project template for VS2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, project-template

I am running VS2010 and Windows 7. I have seen many people with the template for MVVM. Where can I get this template? I already have WPFToolkit installed, but the template does not appear. I tried to go to the sites, like codeplex, that say they have it and it turns out to be the WPFToolkit installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try the first download here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962)

Comment: Does that work with VS2010?  I apparently already have it installed but nothing is showing up.  Also, looking at the dates, it will certainly not be .NET 4 ready.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this template: [WPF MVVM project template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/970005b8-ee15-4295-9960-375e6ea1276c)

Comment: This one is great. Minimal but has the key classes: NotificationObject and DelegateCommand.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other readers/, WPF Model-View-ModelView Toolkit v3.5.50211.1 may be downloaded /from CodePleax, at this URL:

http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit&ProjectName=wpf

According to the web site as of Nov 9, 2011, this toolkit only works for VS2008.  - KRP